# Diferença entre PHP e PHP 64 Bits

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre PHP e PHP 64 Bits.

Eu estava pesquisando sobre o `RealPerson.js`, onde tinha um código para PHP e outro para PHP 64 Bits:

**PHP**

```
function rpHash($value) { 
    $hash = 5381; 
    $value = strtoupper($value); 
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) { 
        $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i)); 
    } 
    return $hash;
} 
if (rpHash($_POST['realPerson'].salt) == $_POST['realPersonHash']) { 
    // Accepted
```

**PHP 64Bit**

```
function rpHash($value) { 
    $hash = 5381; 
    $value = strtoupper($value); 
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) { 
        $hash = (leftShift32($hash, 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i)); 
    } 
    return $hash; 
} 

// Perform a 32bit left shift 
function leftShift32($number, $steps) { 
    // convert to binary (string) 
    $binary = decbin($number); 
    // left-pad with 0's if necessary 
    $binary = str_pad($binary, 32, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    // left shift manually 
    $binary = $binary.str_repeat("0", $steps); 
    // get the last 32 bits 
    $binary = substr($binary, strlen($binary) - 32); 
    // if it's a positive number return it 
    // otherwise return the 2's complement 
    return ($binary{0} == "0" ? bindec($binary) : 
            -(pow(2, 31) - bindec(substr($binary, 1)))); 
} 

if (rpHash($_POST['realPerson'].salt) == $_POST['realPersonHash']) { 
    // Accepted
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basicamente, pelo fato de não se ter tido cuidado de abstrair os formatos numéricos quando foram elaboradas, as funções do PHP tem capacidades numéricas diferentes em cada versão.

Assim, em algumas situações é necessário usar funções próprias no lugar das nativas para o comportamento ser igual nas duas.

No código em questão, em especial nesta parte:

```
$hash << 5
```

Isso funciona desta forma, deslocando o valor 5 bits para a esquerda:

```
11000000 00001000 00000011 00000000
<< 5 =
00000001 00000000 01100000 00000000
```

Se fosse em 64 bits, iria acontecer isso:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11000000 00001000 00000011 00000000
<< 5 =
00000000 00000000 00000000 00011000 00000001 00000000 01100000 00000000
                               ^
                               isto aqui não aconteceria em 32
                               bits, o valor seria truncado, o
                               que geraria resultados diferentes
                               nas duas arquiteturas.
```

Portanto, foi necessário reescrever a funcionalidade do operador `<<`, que é a função `leftShift32($number, $steps)`.

Por sinal, foi refeita de maneira meio "estranha", pois em vez de usar operações de bits, usa diversas conversões e operações de string.

Melhor teria sido fazer uma versão só que funcionasse bem nos 2 casos, e usando a matemática de maneira mais apropriada, do que depender do usuário avaliar qual usar em qual situação.

Comment: Ótima explicação, deu pra entender perfeitamente! Obrigado por me esclarecer isso!!!